# Filebeat read all logs, not only that one defined in configuration

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, filebeat, elk

I try to configure filebeat version 7.17.5 (amd64), libbeat 7.17.5, for reading Spring boot logs and sending them via logstash to elasticsearch. All works fine, logs are send and I can read it in Kibana but the problem is that I configured filebeat in file /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml and defined there only one source of logs, but filebeat's still getting all logs from /var/log

It's my only one config for inputs:

```
filebeat.inputs:
   - type: filestream
     id: some_id
     enabled: true
     paths:
       -  "/var/log/dir_with_logs/application.log"
```

But when I check status of filebeat a have the information that:

```
[input] log/input.go:171 Configured paths: [/var/log/auth.log* /var/log/secure*]
```

And also I have logs from files: auth or secure in Kibana, which I don't want to have.

What I'm doing wrong or what I don't know what I should?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configured paths of `/var/log/auth.log*` and `/var/log/secure*`, I think this is the Filebeat [system module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/filebeat-module-system.html). You can disable the system module by renaming `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/system.yml` to `/etc/filebeat/modules.d/system.yml.disabled`.

Alternatively you can run the [`filebeat modules`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.17/command-line-options.html#modules-command) command to disable the module (it simply renames the file for you).

```
filebeat modules disable system
```